# C# Can not run PowerShell script to add user Active Directory

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to use C# run powershell script for add use to active directory.

This is my C# code for pass parameter to powershell script.

```
public void AddUserNotExpire(string fNm, string lNm, string uNm, string pWd, string gpUsr)
        {


            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            string scriptfile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\addusernotexpire.ps1";
            Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
            CommandParameter p1 = new CommandParameter("fname", fNm);
            CommandParameter p2 = new CommandParameter("lname", lNm);
            CommandParameter p3 = new CommandParameter("uname", uNm);
            CommandParameter p4 = new CommandParameter("pWd", pWd);
            CommandParameter p5 = new CommandParameter("grpUser", gpUsr);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p2);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p3);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p4);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p5);
            pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            // invoke execution on the pipeline (ignore output)
            pipeline.Invoke();
        }
```

This is powershell script file name addusernotexpire.ps1 was call from C#

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $fname,
    [string] $lname,
    [string] $uname,
    [string] $pWd,
    [string] $grpUser 
)

if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $uname})
{
         #If user does exist, give a warning
    Write-Warning "A user account with username $uname already exist in Active Directory."
}
else
{
    New-ADUser `
      -Name $fname `
      -Surname $lname `
      -DisplayName "$fname $lname" `
      -SamAccountName $uname `
      -UserPrincipalName "$uname@test.com" `
      -Enabled $True `
      -Path "OU=$grpUser,DC=test,DC=com" `
      -AccountPassword $pWd| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

}
```

When I run C# code it show error like this. How to fix ?

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
The thread 0x15ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1be0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1690 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Powershell just calls a dotNet API to do this. Why not just use the Active Directory API directly from C#?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to testing it with the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PowershellCallTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AdduserNotExpire(fNm: "first", lNm: null, uNm: "username", pWd: "myPass", gpUser: "myGroup");
        }

        private static void AdduserNotExpire(string fNm, string lNm, string uNm, string pWd, string gpUser)
        {
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            string scriptfile = @"C:\temp\addusernotexpire.ps1";
            Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
            CommandParameter p1 = new CommandParameter("fname", fNm);
            CommandParameter p2 = new CommandParameter("lname", lNm);
            CommandParameter p3 = new CommandParameter("uname", uNm);
            CommandParameter p4 = new CommandParameter("pWd", pWd);
            CommandParameter p5 = new CommandParameter("grpUser", gpUser);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p2);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p3);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p4);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(p5);
            pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            // invoke execution on the pipeline (ignore output)
            pipeline.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And simplified Powerhsell Code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $fname,
    [string] $lname,
    [string] $uname,
    [string] $pWd,
    [string] $grpUser 

Write-Warning "A user account with username $uname already exist"
```

I seems to work fine in my environment.

To get an error like you "System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException"

I have to change the binding, example:

```
CommandParameter p1 = new CommandParameter("unknownparam", fNm);
```

So my assumption is:

You may not call the correct Powershell Script and that why you get this error. Could you please check if the parameters in Powershell on your machine are the same?

If you running your debugger in C# you should also be able to look at the exception and see which parameter:

[image: Debug Exception Error]